# Using offline basemap

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

My app needs to work offline because we have problems with signal internet 3G and can't downloading images from our servers. Somebody know how can do it ?

Now I'm using API Arcgis JS 3.1 and my basemap is

```
var basemap = new esri.layers.OpenStreetMapLayer();
```

I'm trying to install a OpenStreetMap local server in Ubuntu VM.
I will check it.

Comment: Do you need to use ESRI Basemaps? There are plenty of OFFLINE OpenStreeMap Projects - official http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap

Answer (score 1):

try [gmapcatcher](http://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/) - just found it last night but it seems to do the trick for us (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72539/download-esri-world-imagery-basemap-for-offline-use) - search and rescue team needs satellite imagery while in the field, offline - I thought we specifically needed ESRI World Imagery, but bing uses the same 0.3m-per-pixel in our area)

You can download the tiles while online, then transfer them to your offline system by portable hard drive etc.  Surely there's a way to reshuffle the downloaded tile files into such a structure that the local map server can serve them.  (a script if nothing else - surely someone's already done this??)